# What is the rootvg in AIX?

Tags: unix, aix

What is the rootvg in AIX?  Is it something that is unique to AIX?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rootvg` is, as the name suggests, the volume group (`vg`) that contains `/` (`root`) and any other logical volumes you created during installation -- it's basically the default AIX volume group.

Volume Groups (`VG`s) are an AIX thing -- they're basically logical disks (comprised of one or more Physical Volumes (`PV`s).  Logical Volumes (`LV`s -- "partitions") are created inside volume groups.

http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/portals/unix has an "LVM from A to Z" book that goes into lots more detail (as well as a ton of other great reference books for AIX & the Power family of systems -- all free :)

Comment: Public Service Warning: Once you get used to the AIX volume manager you may find yourself cursing the inferiority of all other LVM systems :-)

Comment: Well, the limitations of the rootvg in virtualisation with vios could be... less limited - but I may be remembering in error though I instinctively recall some kind of trouble resizing the rootvg in that setup ^^

Comment: I know there are a few funky "Because it's the damn rootvg, that's why!" items in the LVM docs (don't remember any virtualization ones but mirroring the rootvg has some tricks to it).  None ever really bugged me though :)